# how to deal with a class by string in PHP

Tags: php

I have a call lets assume its called A

```
public class A{
...
}
```

how can I access the members of this class while I have the name of the class

what I need is something like this

```
{"A"}::x=5;
```

instead of

```
A::x=5;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Foo {
    const BAR = 'bar';
    public static $baz = 'baz';
}

$foo = 'Foo';
echo $foo::BAR;
echo $foo::$baz;
```

This requires PHP 5.3+ though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ReflectionClass`

```
class A {
        public static $x = 5;
}

$class = new ReflectionClass('A');
echo $class->getStaticPropertyValue('x');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php